# Prove that $2^n > 10n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$ using calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

My approach to doing these types of questions is finding the derivative of the LHS and the RHS and finding the limit of that derivative as $n$ approaches infinity. So, for this question, it would be:

Let $f(x) = 2^n$ --> $f'(x) = 2^nlog(2)$

Let $g(x) = 10n^2$ --> $g'(x) = 20n$

But I don't know how to proceed from here using limits as $n$ goes to infinity. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may use induction

Comment: But since the question states "using calculus", so that's not the expected way here.

Comment: You can use the binomial theorem too $(1+1)^n=1^n+n\cdot 1^{n-1}\cdot 1+\binom n2\cdot 1^{n-2}1^2+\binom n3\cdot 1^{n-3}1^3+\dots\gt \binom n3$ - the binomial coefficient is cubic in $n$ and is greater than $10n^2$ for $n$    large enough by an easy argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true for all $n\geq10$.

Indeed, $$f''(x)=2^x\ln^22-20>0$$
$$f'(x)=2^x\ln2-20x>0$$ and from here $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: But why is it valid to take the second derivative in this case? I thought it was the first derivative that determines whether something increases or decreases.

Comment: Since $f''>0$, we see that $f'$ increases, which says $f'(x)>f'(10)>0,$ which gives that $f$ increases and $f(x)>f(10)>0.$

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

define $$f(n)=2^n-10n^2$$ then we get
$$f'(n)=2^n\ln(2)-20n$$
$$f''(n)=2^n(\ln(2))^2-20$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Is it that $2^n(ln(2))^2 > 20$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: yes it is for $$n>\frac{20}{(\ln(2))^3}$$ and this is $$n>61$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand why we are allowed to take the second derivative to determine this in this case. I thought only the first derivative determines increase or decrease

Comment: and it is $$2^n\ln(2)>20n$$ for $$n\geq 8$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2^n=\exp(n\log(2))=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{n^k\log^k(2)}{k!}$$
$$2^n-10n^2=1+n\log(2)+n^2\left(\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}-10\right)+n^3\frac{\log^3(2)}{6}+\sum_{k\geq4}\frac{n^k\log^k(2)}{k!}$$
So:
$$2^n-10n^2\geq1+n\log(2)+n^2\left(\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}-10\right)+n^3\frac{\log^3(2)}{6}=:f(n)$$
The coefficient of $n^2$ is less than $0$, but the coefficient of $n^3$ is greater than $0$.
For $a$,$b$,$c$,$d \geq0$: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}ax^3-bx^2+cx+d=\infty$, so $f(n)$ will be positive for large enough $n$. And since $2^n-10n^2\geq f(n)$, $2^n-10n^2$ will be also greater than $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2^n > 10 n^2 \iff  n\times log(2) > 1+2\times log(n)\iff  $$

$$ n \times log(2)  -2\times log(n)> 1\iff $$

$$n\ge10$$

Comment: I am unsure how you got $1 + 2log(n)$ on the RHS of the first line

Comment: $log( 10 n^2) = log(10) + log(n^2) = 1+ 2log(n)$

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing it would be

Let $f(x) = 2^x - 10x^2$ (which is continuous) then

$f'(x) = 2^x*\ln 2 - 20x$.

$f''(x) = 2^x*(\ln 2)^2 - 20$

$f'''(x) = 2^x *(\ln 2)^2 > 0;$ for all $x$.

So $f''(x)$ is strictly increasing.  If there is any $x_2$ where $f''(x_2) \ge 0$ then $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x > x_2$.

Which means $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing for all $x > x_2$.  If there is an $x_1$ where $x_1 \ge x_2$ and $f'(x_1) > 0$ then $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x >x_1$.

Which means $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for all $x > x_1$.  So if there is an $x_0$ and $x_0 \ge x_1$ and $f(x_0) > 0$ then $f(n)>0$ and $2^n > 10n^2$ for all $n > x_0$.  Hence our result.

Now to find these $x_0,x_1,x_2$.... well, there is no need for accuracy.... we can be as crude as we like.

We want $2^x_2*(\ln 2)^2 > 20$, just let $x_2 > \log_2 (\frac {20}{(\ln 2)^2})$.  No need for accuracy:  $\frac 12 < \ln 2 < 1$; $\frac 14(\ln 2)^2<1$ so $20< \frac {20}{(\ln 2)^2}<80$ so $4=\log_2 16 < \log_2 20< \log_2 \frac {20}{(\ln 2)^2} < \log_2 80 < \log_2 128 = 7$ so let $x_2 = 7$.

We want $2^{x_1}*\ln 2 - 20x$ so... I dunno... $\ln 2 > \frac 23$ so $2^{8}\ln 2 - 160 > 256*2/3 - 160 > 170 - 160 = 10 > 0$ so $x_1 = 8$ will do.

Just need to find *any* $x_0 \ge 8$ so that $2^{x_0} \ge 10x_0^2$.  $x_0 = 10$ will do as $2^{10} = 2014 > 1000 = 10*10^2$.

So that's it.  For any $n \ge 10$ we have proven $2^n > 10*n^2$.